# SQLite Update Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have tables with the following structure:

```
TimeStamp,
var_1,
var_2,
var_3,
var_4,
var_5,...
```

This contains about 600 columns named var_##, the user parses some data stored by a machine and I have to update all null values inside that table to the last valid value. At the moment I use the following query:

```
update tableName 
    set var_##  = 
            (select   b.var_##  from   tableName  as 
                      where b.timeStamp <=   tableName.timeStamp and   b.var_##   is not null  
                      order by timeStamp desc limit 1)  
    where   tableName.var_##   is null;
```

Problem right now is the tame it takes to run this query for all columns, is there any way to optimize this query?

UPDATE: this is the output query plan when executin te query for one column:

```
update wme_test2 
set var_6  = 
        (select   b.var_6  from   wme_test2  as b
                        where b.timeStamp <=   wme_test2.timeStamp and   b.var_6   is not null  
                        order by timeStamp desc limit 1)  
   where   wme_test2.var_6   is null;
```

[image]

Comment: i would split this into 2 tables so you don't have a 600 column table

Answer (score 1):

Having 600 indexes on the data columns would be silly. (But not necessarily more silly than having 600 columns.)

All queries can be sped up with an index on the `timeStamp` column.

Comment: well, i had already tried with  both the index on timeStamp and without the index without significant difference on the time it takes to run those queries. Since all other columns are dependant on this column and tables are more often used too create tableviews I thought it would be best to keep all in one table than create small groups and join them for visualization. What do you suggest? create more tables grouping variables how?

Comment: Thank you for telling us *now*. Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.